# Auto-refresh my page so that an if condition is continually checked

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have the following If-condition.

```
if (entry.Status1 != string.Empty) // I want this condition to continue to be checked while the user is on the page. 
{
    lblStatus.Text = entry.Status2; 
}
```

I need to have my page continuously reload/refresh automatically so that this condition is constantly being checked. I do not want the user to have to refresh the page. How do I do this in ASP.Net? Do I use Ajax? If so, how do I programatically do that? Any better methods?

Comment: What is causing the `entry.Status1` to change? Can you provide more code so we can get the context?

Comment: In addition to @Wellspring comment, is this ASP.Net Web Form or ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: It's a field in my database.  We have a monitor that runs and watches an activity.  The activity has many fields such as the name, description, final status, dependent status...etc.  So basically once the activity is done running it will update the entry.Status1 value.  Those details really aren't important though.  I just need to know how to refresh my .aspx page every 5 seconds.

Comment: This is an ASP.Net Web Form

Comment: You have an exact same question that is a little bit older. Delete [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536970/auto-refresh-my-page-so-that-an-if-condition-is-continually-checked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UpdatePanel` with a `Timer`

On the aspx page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Literal ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in code behind

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
    {
        lblStatus.Text = TextBox1.Text + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can set the interval of the timer with `Interval="5000"`, units are in milliseconds.

But you are also talking about a `monitor that runs and watches an activity`. This sounds more like a task running in the background. To make a complex task that runs in the background I would recommend [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)